# How to add data to a blank file in php?

Tags: php, html, file, printing, append

I have been trying to get this code to work but it wouldn't. I'm trying to create a program which adds in information to a file and it created a file and add data.
 
Sorry about the rookie mistakes.

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $comment=$_POST['stuff'];
    file_put_contents("names.txt",$names. PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    $names=file("names.txt");
    $i=count($names);
    file_put_contents("$i.txt",$comment);}
    $names=file("names.txt");
    foreach ($names as $name){
        file_get_contents("$i.txt");
        print "$name[$i]:$Name: #Comment";
    }
}
```

Comment: have you had success with solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here what you can try

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $comment = $_POST["stuff"];
    $myFile = fopen("names.txt", "a"); //Here "a" means every time you submit, it appends data to existing "names.txt".
    fwrite($myFile, "Name: ".$name."\n\r");
    fwrite($myFile, "Comment: ".$comment."\n\r");
    fclose($myFile);
    echo "$name: $comment"; //here I used "echo" instead of "print"

}
```

Now, when you submit another form, It puts the content to existing "names.txt" without erasing it's text.

Comment: you are just writing the text in "names.txt" but mine, appending in it!

Answer (score -1):

you can create a file using the `fopen()` function as follows:

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])){

  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $comment=$_POST['stuff'];

  $myFile = fopen("names.txt", "w");
  fwrite($myFile, "Name: ".$name."\n");
  fwrite($myFile, "Comment: ".$comment."\n");
  fclose($myFile);

  echo "Name: ".$name."<br>Comment: ".$comment."<br>";

}
```

The previous code creates a new text file. If you wish to add information to an existing file, all you do is change the following line:

```
  $myFile = fopen("names.txt", "w");
```

into this line:

```
  $myFile = fopen("names.txt", "a");
```

Let me know if that worked for you! :)

Comment: use "fwrite" instead of "$fwrite"